# Event once all the custom item renderers have been created/set

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

I'm using a custom item renderer in my datagrid, and need to make a button visible or invisible based on if there has been a negative value on any of the values in the renderer. So I'd like to set a flag to false when the first renderer is set off, turn it to true if there's any negative values, and at the end check for the value of the flag. I know I can dispatch a dataChange event for every time the data is changed in the renderer instances, but I was wondering if there is anyway I can know when all of them are done?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such event.

Like any other Flex component, a renderer will dispatch a `CREATION_COMPLETE` after it's been created.  `ItemRenderers` are generally recycled (the same object gets assigned new data to render), thus listening for `CREATION_COMPLETE` is not sufficient, unless you disable the recycling.

For a Spark `List` component, you can disable recycling by setting `useVirtualLayout=false` on the layout class. I'm not sure if the Spark `DataGrid` class support this or not. The MX DataGrid may have some other way to do this.

Disabling the recycling, however, can have performance implications. I think your idea w/the `DATA_CHANGE` event is the best solution:

- determine the initial state of the data (ie: are there any negative values)
- in the renderer, use the DATA_CHANGE event (or just override the setter for the renderer's `data` property) to know when the data has changed
- When the data changes, dispatch a custom event class that will bubble. This event has a property that tells you if the value is negative or not.
- Since your custom event from the renderers will bubble up to the grid, you can add one listener on the grid to handle changes from all the renderers.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm mainly confused about how I can know when the first ItemRenderer is used, and when the last one in my grid is done. Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: You cannot. Each renderer will dispatch creation complete once (when they are created), and data change **every** time the data changes. Since you are giving the grid the initial data, you know if any values are initially negative. After that, you must use the data change event to look for negative values as described above.

Comment: Sorry, I think I'm not explaining my problem very well :)
I need to be able to tell if there's a negative value everytime the set of cells in my grid are rendered. So say the first time all of them are renderered, and one of the values was negative, so I set a flag as True. The next time the user scrolls down in the grid, I want it to be a clean slate, so I want to set the flag as false again, and again if any of the renderers gets a negative value I'll set it as true.But I guess there's no real way to set the flag as false in the beginning of every 'set' of renderings. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Oh, I got it...I could just set an event handler for a scroll event for that grid. Sorry, stupid of me.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look into RendererExistenceEvents. You should be able to tell when they are all created based on how many items you have in your list or at least how many should be in view at once.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/events/RendererExistenceEvent.html